# How to pass char array to char** argument

Tags: c++

I have one function which have argument as `char**` I need to pass an array value in the same argument how could I pass that?

```
int fun(char** val)
{
  std::cout<<"val:"<<*val<<"\n";
}

int main()
{
  char ch[20];
  strlcpy(ch, "test", sizeof(ch));

  fun(&ch[0]) // here how can I pass the char array getting build issue
}
```

Comment: What is the expected output? And `strlcpy(ch, "test", sizeof(ch));` doesn't make much sense, what do ylou expect the `ch` array to contain after?

Comment: @Jabberwocky that too, `ch` is unitialized. not sure in CPP, in C, using `ch` as a _string_ will get you into trouble.

Comment: `int fun(char *val)` and then `fun(ch);` will allow you to pass the array `ch` to `fun()` which will then output the first char, or `std::cout << "val:"<<val<<'\n';` to output the entire contents.

Comment: `strlcpy()` is just `strcpy()` with bounds checking added, similar to `strncpy()`. This code is copying `"test"` into `ch`.

Comment: Why is this tagged C++? I don't see any, other than the `cout`...

Comment: `std::cout` squeaks it by...

Comment: @RemyLebeau correct me if I'm wrong, but `strlcpy(ch, "test", sizeof(ch))` is just copying `"T"` into `ch`

Comment: @Jabberwocky you are wrong. “*The `strlcpy()` function copies up to `size - 1` characters from the NUL-terminated string `src` to `dst`, NUL-terminating the result.*” Here, `dst` is `ch`, `src` is `”test”`, and `size` is `sizeof(ch)` aka 20. So it copies the entire `”test”` into `ch`.

Comment: @RemyLebeau I was writing total nonsense, I misread `ch` as `char`, sorry, we can delete the comments dealing with this. Need some coffee

Comment: Thanks for reply! I am aware that if we have ```fun(char* val)``` and ```char ch[]``` then we can pass as ```fun(ch)```. And if ```fun(char** val)``` and ```char* ch``` then i can pass as ```fun(&ch)```. My issue i am using one static tool which is giving the issue for validation required for the ```fun``` argument, and there i can not pass as above i have mentioned and i need to pass ```char arr[]``` into ```char**``` argument of fun.

Comment: @YogendraKumar you didn't need to repeat the same comment multiple times.

Answer (score 2):

I think it is best to figure out, what the intent of the function `fun` is on the basis of the signature, i.e. the type of the parameter:

`fun` takes a pointer to a pointer to a single character or to the beginning of a bunch of characters. In the first place this means `fun` wants to have a "reference" to a pointer. This usually means `func` wants to modify this pointer and pass this modification back to the caller. It seams `val` is in fact an out parameter containing a pointer. If this is you actual intend, go with this function signature! In this case you would call `fun` this way:

```
char *c = NULL;
fun(&c);
// c is set by fun to a certain value
```

If you simply want to print out the characters it is way easier and much more obvious for a reader of your code to change the signature of `fun` to

```
int fun(char *val) { /* ... */ }
```

This says `fun` takes a pointer to a single character or a bunch of characters. It will get this pointer by value, any modification to the pointer itself won't be visibly outside of `fun`. In this case you'll call `fun` by

```
char c[] = "Hello World!";
fun(c);
```

Now, why did you get a build issue: The type of `&ch[0]` is `char *`, i.e. a pointer to some characters. But your `fun` expected `char **`, i.e. a pointer to a pointer to some characters. That's clearly an issue. And it contradicts the intend expressed by the function signature too: `fun` wants to have a "reference" to a pointer in order to modify this referenced pointer.

**Edit:** So, it sounds like you're stuck with a weird API and need to pass an character array into a function expecting a `char **` parameter. In this case the other answers provide the correct, albeit still questionable solution:

```
char c[] = "Hello World";
char *ptr = &c[0];
fun(&ptr);
```

The `ptr` points to the first character of `c`. The variable `ptr` has itself an address, namely `&ptr`, which has type `char **`. So `&ptr` is the needed "reference" to a pointer to a bunch of characters you can pass to `fun`.

But be aware of the fact, that `fun` is free to change the value of `ptr`, i.e. the address `ptr` itself points to. It might be possible that, returning from the call to `fun`, the value of `ptr` is something completely different, pointing to an address you didn't expect. Heck, it might be even possible that you're expected to call `free(ptr)` at the end even though you started with an address in `ptr` to some static memory you shall never call `free()` to. **To know these details you have to read the detailed specifications of the function `fun`.**

Comment: Thanks for reply! I am aware that if we have ```fun(char* val)``` and ```char ch[]``` then we can pass as ```fun(ch)```. And if ```fun(char** val``` and ```char* ch``` then i can pass as ```fun(&ch)```. My issue i am using one static tool which is giving the issue for validation required for the ```fun``` argument, and there i can not pass as above i have mentioned and i need to pass ```char arr[]``` into ```char**``` argument of fun.

Answer (score 1):

`ch` is a `char[]` array. `&ch[0]` is dereferencing the array to access the 1st element, yielding a `char`, and then is taking the address of that `char`, yielding a `char*`. But the function wants a `char**` instead. So save that `char*` to a variable and pass the address of that variable to the function, eg:

```
int main()
{
    char ch[20];
    strlcpy(ch, "test", sizeof(ch));
    char *ptr = ch; // same as: ptr = &ch[0] 
    fun(&ptr);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for reply! I am aware that if we have ```fun(char* val)``` and ```char ch[]``` then we can pass as ```fun(ch)```. And if ```fun(char** val)``` and ```char* ch``` then i can pass as ```fun(&ch)```. My issue i am using one static tool which is giving the issue for validation required for the ```fun``` argument, and there i can not pass as above i have mentioned and i need to pass ```char arr[]``` into ```char**``` argument of fun.

Comment: @YogendraKumar there is no way to *directly* pass a `char[20]` fixed array to a `char**` pointer, they are different types. What exactly is the validation tool complaining about?

Comment: @Caleth `&ch` is a `char(*)[20]`, aka a pointer to a `char[20]` array. That type cannot be assigned to a `char**`, aka a pointer to a pointer to a `char`. They are different types.

Comment: I stand corrected. Had I thought about it more, I would have realised that array->pointer decay results in an rvalue `char *`, which isn't valid for `operator&`